# Correlation with sliding window

Tags: r, correlation, sliding-window

I want to compute a pearson correlation between two vectors (each four elements) with a slinding window (window=1) and keep the best result:

```
list1 <- read.table(text= "20 
                           34
                           89
                           35")

list2 <- read.table(text= "22
                          99 
                          313 
                          13 
                          71 
                          200")
```

The comparison will be a loop on:

```
cor(x=c(20,34,89,35),y=c(22,99,313,13), method = "pearson")  
cor(x=c(20,34,89,35),y=c(99,313,13,71), method = "pearson")
cor(x=c(20,34,89,35),y=c(313,13,71,200), method = "pearson")
```

The result will contain the score and the vectors that give the highest correlation score. In this case it will be: `x=c(20,34,89,35) and y=c(22,99,313,13)` and `0.9588095`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `rollapply` compute the correlations, find the index of the largest one and derive `y` and its correlation with `x` from that.

```
library(zoo)

x <- list1$V1
w <- length(x)
ix <- which.max(rollapply(list2$V1, w, cor, x))
y <- list2$V1[seq(ix, length = w)]

y
## [1]  22  99 313  13

cor(x, y)
## [1] 0.9588095
```

A variation of the above is to return the correlation and the y vector from `rollapply`:

```
r <- rollapply(list2$V1, length(x), function(y) c(cor(x, y), y))
ix <- which.max(r[, 1])

r[ix, 1]
## [1] 0.9588095

r[ix, -1]
## [1]  22  99 313  13
```

Answer (score 0):

An R base solution

```
out <- list(NULL)
j <- 1
ind <- 0
while(ind[length(ind)]<length(list2$V1)){ 
  ind <- j:(j+3);
  out[[j]] <- list(Vector1=list1$V1, 
                Vector2=list2$V1[ind],
                Cor=cor(list1$V1, list2$V1[ind]));
  out
  j <- j+1
}

out[[which.max(unlist(sapply(out, "[", "Cor")))]]
```

which produces:

```
$Vector1
[1] 20 34 89 35

$Vector2
[1]  22  99 313  13

$Cor
[1] 0.9588095
```